# Problem parametrizing this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, parametrization

I have a system of equations:

$$x_1 + x_2 + 3x_3 − 2x_4 − x_5 = 1$$
$$5x_1 − 2x_2 + 3x_3 + 7x_4 + 8x_5 = 3,$$
$$−3x_1 − x_2 + 2x_3 + 7x_4 + 5x_5 = 2,$$
$$5x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3 − 2x_4 − 7x_5 = 3$$

With Gaussian elimination, I reach:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J8BF.jpg)

How can I use parametrization to solve for x,x2...

Comment: You need to end up with [this matrix](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B1%2C1%2C3%2C-2%2C-1%2C1%7D%2C%7B5%2C-2%2C3%2C7%2C8%2C3%7D%2C%7B-3%2C-1%2C2%2C7%2C5%2C2%7D%2C%7B5%2C3%2C1%2C-2%2C-7%2C3%7D%7D).

Comment: Yes, for starters, your echelon form is badly wrong. But then the crucial thing is that you need to reduce the matrix to *reduced echelon form* in order to read off the general solution. You can find that explained in every linear algebra text.

Comment: @TedShifrin why is my echelon form wrong?

Comment: @TedShifrin I though you could find the general solution parametrizing the echelon form with the free variable

Comment: @aziff00 linked you the correct answer from Wolfram Alpha. Your answer is wrong because it is wrong. Since you did not post every step of your work, we cannot guess what you've done wrong. This subject is notoriously challenging if one makes the slightest arithmetic errors. ... Again, you need *reduced* echelon form to read off the equations for the pivot variables in terms of the free variables. Go read the text or watch some videos.

Comment: Please [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and don't rely on images.